# What is the alternative to JQuery`s deprecated delegate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I asked a question about sending data from a class to it's parent class (I know js has no classes but I've used prototype).

[Sending data from classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056400/sending-data-from-classes)

It was suggested to use delegate.

I read some more about delegate and find in the jquery docs it's out of date. So what should I be using? on? If so how would it work in my example? All the examples for .on refer to buttons or dom elements.

Comment: "and find in the jquery docs it's out of date" --- can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: the term to describe out-of-dateness in the programming world is `deprecated`.

Comment: Note that the answer you're linking to talks about delegating in general, not about jQuery's `.delegate()`. Delegating *as a concept* itself isn't "out of date".

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: your change is not correct - it was **NOT** deprecated. At least jquery dev team didn't state they deprecate it.

Comment: So is what was suggested correct?

Comment: `delegate` method isn't deprecated, it has been superseded by the .on() method, not the same thing

Comment: @zerkms Oh I never saw that. I knew it was an older method though so I assumed it was. Sorry.

Comment: Can someone please just answer my questions and stop going out about whether it was depreciated or not

Comment: @user3710433 You have already your answer... Use preferably on()

Comment: @A.Wolff My question asked for an example of this

Comment: @user3710433 We aren't paid to provide you copy/paste sample of whatever you want, make some research, read the DOC, take some initiative

Comment: The OP's question has nothing to do with `.delegate()`. It's just a misunderstanding based on similar variable names in the other question. As such it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Juhana So what is the question??? Are you referring to older question posted as link here?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes. *"I asked a question [..] It was suggested to use delegate."* But the other question's answer *didn't* suggest to use `.delegate()` -- the OP only thought so and got confused by the API saying it's deprecated. The answer to the question is "`.delegate()` is deprecated, but you weren't told to use it, so no problems". The answer "use `.on()` instead" is of no use to the OP.

Comment: @Juhana Ok i see what you mean after reading OP's older question

Comment: @Juhana quite right, post it as an answer an i'll accept it

Comment: I can't post an answer because the question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery Doc:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation.

So, it's not out of date, it's just that another method is preferred in newer versions. AFAIK it is still existing for backwards compatibility.

In fact, the `delegate()` method in newer jQuery versions calls the `on()` method but switches up the parameters.

[**Delegate in jQuery 1.7+**](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.delegate)

```
function (selector, types, data, fn) {
    return this.live(types, data, fn, selector);
}
```

TL;DR: For jQuery versions prior to 1.7, use `delegate()`. For newer versions, use `on()`.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: @user3710433: it does answer your only "What is the alternative to JQuery`s deprecated delegate()?" question.

Comment: @user3710433 Looks like hard time for everyone to get your question

Comment: @user3710433 TL;DR: For jQuery versions prior to 1.7, use delegate(). For newer versions, use on().

Comment: Guys, thats what has been on my mind also. I made a fiddle illustrating problem im having with this issue. clicking on div will make event fire twice, even if the container does not have ".b" class anymore    http://jsfiddle.net/TEP3X/
and im not interested in using "one()". I just wanna dynamic event, dependent on node having class

Comment: @entio How is that related? Ask your own question.

Comment: @oGeez; Jeez i was trying to search it and am afraid of stack nazis... couldnt You yust tell my what to seek for?

Comment: @entio Stack Nazis? Write a good question, with evidence of your own research, what you have and what you desire. If it's a good enough question it'll stay open. You can't expect people to guess what you want.

Comment: @user3710433 You should be more polite with people trying to help you... Now i guess, many will stop trying to help you, i hope

Comment: Sorry for being dumb. Jquery documentation is sooo clearly about this.

Comment: @entio `$(document.body).on('click','div.a.b',func...` http://api.jquery.com/on/ It means you listen to the container of element(s) you're interested in. when you change the html the click will still fire on the container. Behind the scenes jQuery will check if the clicked element satisfies the second selector and if so it'll fire your listener. `$('selector').on('click',functi...` will add the event listener to that element and changing the classes on that element won't undo that.