# Using on to listen for an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class that calls another class.

Using jquery .on() how can I listen for events taking place in the child class, from the parent class.

I'm aware that there are no classes in javascript, I have set it up via prototyping.

This is what I have but I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here's the code:

```
this.fileDrop = new lp.FileDrop();

this.on("test", function(){alert('a'});
```

Here's my class:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var Loon = function () {
        this.init();
    };

    p.init = function () {
        this.fileDrop = new lp.FileDrop();

        this.on("test", function () {
            console.log('a')
        });
    };

    lp.Loon = Loon;
}(window));

var loon;

$(function () {
    loon = new lp.Loon();
});
```

Comment: Have you created the event test?

Comment: We need to see more code.  You likely have not created the prototype function .on() for js objects.  Perhaps try $(this).on() if thats the event binding functionality to are going for?

Comment: Yes I trigger it in my child class. But I commented it out, the above this.on line causes the error.

Comment: becuase `this` does not have `on`

Comment: So what should I use instead of this?

Comment: We have no clue what `this` is...

Comment: I;ve updated the post with the class.

Comment: You're code makes no sense; `p` does not exist in `p.init`. What line do you get the error on?

Comment: Error on:  this.on("test", function () {

Comment: You'd have better to provide a jsFiddle which replicate your issue

Answer (score 1):

I've seen roughly the same question come back a couple of times now, it's [already answered by Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057205/1641941) a while ago but he forgot to use bind in his examples so `this` is not resolved as you'd like it to be. Hope the following helps a bit:

```
function DropBox(mainClassInstance){
  this.delegate=mainClassInstance;
  $(document.body).on("click",this.drop.bind(this));
}
DropBox.prototype.drop=function(e){
  console.log("window event triggered in dropbox instance");
  this.delegate.drop(e);
}

function MainClass(){
  this.dropBox=new DropBox(this);
}
MainClass.prototype.drop=function(){
  console.log("drop in mainclass, dropbox is:",this.dropBox);
}
var m = new MainClass();
```

The following answer may help you out with creating objects in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941